# How to invoke scheduled task on Server 2008 from XP client using schtasks

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-task

We are running a scheduled task on a Server 2008 machine from an XP client.  Using the following commandline (on the XP client):

```
schtasks /run /u "domain\username" /p "password" /s MyServer2008 /tn MyTask
```

This reports SUCCESS, but the task is not actually being run.  Querying using schtasks on the server shows that the task has never been run.

Is there anything configuration or other factors that could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the task isn't set to only run when the user is logged in (*yes, even though the task reports as success*). Check your event logs for errors associated with scheduled tasks. `schtasks` isn't the final word on a tasks behavior.